# OneStepCheckout not redirecting to 3rd party payment gateway - Magento 1.9.4

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout

I am using MageStore OneStepCheckout version 3.5.1 with Magento 1.9.4 CE. I am using [2Checkout payment gateway](https://github.com/craigchristenson/magento-2checkout) on my website. However, when I press Place Order button at checkout, it doesnt redirect to the payment gateway. After pressing the button, nothing happens but the order actually gets placed.

I was using the same payment gateway with OneStepCheckout one or two years back and it used to work fine. Now, I am moving back to this payment gateway and its not working. However, another thing to note is that it works fine with the default Magento Checkout. Please have this issue resolve. I also tested it with the latest 3.7.1 version but that gives the same issue.

I have also submitted a ticket to the MageStore but they seem to have discontinued the extension so I dont really expect a solution from them. It would be really helpful if you guys can help me solve this problem as I dont really want to spend for a new one step checkout extension.